# How to combine array in php to dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have code like this

```
$a =[
      [1,2],
      [4,6],
      [10,24]
    ];
```

i want a output like this

```
    Array
    (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 2
      [2] => 4
      [3] => 6
      [4] => 10
      [5] => 24
    )
```

and i use code like this

```
print_r(array_merge($a[0],$a[1],$a[2]));
```

if a have code like this and have more data

```
    Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 24
        )
       .
       .
       .
     [60] => Array
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 8
     )
```

writing like this is not good

```
print_r(array_merge($a[0],$a[1],$a[2],...,...,...,$a[58]));
```

how to use `array_merge` in dinamic in there?

Comment: You simply do `array_merge(...$a))`. https://3v4l.org/QIBdU

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following function.

```
function func($array) { 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
      if (is_array($value)) { 
        $result = array_merge($result, func($value)); 
      } 
      else { 
        $result[$key] = $value; 
      } 
    } 
    return $result; 
  }
```

Comment: It uses recursion for accommodate for multiple levels of depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function my_array_merge($array1, $array2) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $array1[$key] = my_array_merge($array1[$key], $array2[$key]);
        } else {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $array1[] = $array2[$key];
            } else {
                $array1[$key] = $array2[$key];
            }
        }
    }
    return $array1;
}
```

As far as I know, the above exactly works like `array_merge()`, but merges  arrays inside it:

```
$arr1 = array(array("a"));
$arr2 = array(array("b"));
```

will become:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
        )
)
```

Comment: ya,, but its not in two array, but one in array to marge... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

u can use this:

```
$a =[
      7,
      [1,2],
      [4,6],
      [10,24],
      [[30,40],[2,9]]
    ];

function mrg($array){
    $out = [];
    foreach($array as $b){
        if(is_array($b))
            $out = array_merge($out, mrg($b));
        else
            $out[] = $b;
    }
    return $out;
}

print_r(mrg($a));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its so good... tks

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_reduce($a, fn($carry, $item) => array_merge($carry, $item), []);
```